# Is is possible to override equals without using instanceof and getClass?

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I want to override `equals(Object o)` without using `instanceof`, `getClass()` and casting. Is this doable in Java and if yes how it is possiable?
Editing: And I want to use this method too.
For example: I want to override this method in class Cow and use it to check if my Cow logically equals to other Cow?

Thanks for answers everyone. My main problem is that: what happens if I send Car as other class to my cow or any other Object. How can I check if Object o got method `getName()` (Assuming my Cow got this method)?

Comment: You want to override it for a custom object you created?

Comment: Sure.  `boolean equals(Object o) { return true; }`

Comment: @SLaks : that would violate the contract of the equals() method, which should return false for null arguments.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `instanceof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Make `Cow` serializable, and make sure that its serialized form is canonical (worst case by implementing `Externalizable` and hand-writing your own serialization that is canonical) and then do the following in `equals`:

1. Try to serialize the argument.  If that fails, return false.
2. Serialize `this`.
3. Compare the serialized bytes of the two.

Since the serial form includes a string identifying the type, it includes the bytes necessary to distinguish instances of different types.

This isn't easy, is inefficient, is probably a maintenance nightmare, and should definitely not be your first choice, but it does demonstrate that there are language tricks available to Java code that will allow type distinction without `instanceof` or `Class` sameness checks.

One caveat though: the serial form does not distinguish between classes with the same name loaded in different class loaders.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible if the criteria for equality are limited to using information that is only available from an Object.

This /seems/ unlikely... why would you be overriding `equals` if you were only using `Object`'s methods? However, there's nothing to prevent you from doing it, if this is appropriate for your design.

Just be sure that you maintain the contract defined in the [Javadocs for `equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)